# Save nested dictionary with array of numbers into CSV file

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have a dictionary (cell_summary) with 46 items(b1c0,b1c1,b1c2..) in it. Each item in "cell_summary" is a dictionary with 8 items in it. Each of the 8 items is an array of numbers. I would like to convert the 46 items as 46 sheets in a single CSV or excel workbook. 8 key names must be the column names in each sheet and the corresponding data should come in the same column. See the images attached to get a clear Idea of the data. Each sheet in the CSV file should have all the 8 field names and the values in the array must appear in the column of the corresponding field.

I tried the below code. But, all the values in the array are being stored in only one cell of the CSV file. Please see the attached image for reference.

Please help me with this.

```
import csv
import itertools

with open("Cell Summary.csv", 'w', newline='' )as f:

    fields = ['IR', 'QC', 'QD', 'Tavg', 'Tmin', 'Tmax', 'chargetime', 'cycle']
    w = csv.DictWriter( f, fields )
    for key,val in sorted(cell_summary.items()):
        row = {'IR': key}
        row.update(val)
        w.writerow(row)
```

[image: Structure of data in Cell_summary]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing a dictionary, it is easier to write a Dataframe as shown in the following implementation. You will need `openpyxl` installed, see the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for how to install.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
diction={'b1c0':{'IR':np.arange(1,100,1),'QC':np.arange(1,100,1),'QD':np.arange(1,100,1)},
        'b1c1':{'IR':np.arange(1,100,1),'QC':np.arange(1,100,1),'QD':np.arange(1,100,1)},
        'b1c2':{'IR':np.arange(1,100,1),'QC':np.arange(1,100,1),'QD':np.arange(1,100,1)}}

for df_name, df in diction.items():
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=df_name)
writer.save()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Sameeresque . Thank you so much. Really helped me a lot. :)

Comment: How can I do the same job if the lengths of each array in the dictionary(diction) are different? In the above example  code you have mentioned, if "IR" , "QC", "QD" are arrays of size  100, 150, 120. Then How can I do it? I tried but it says "ARRAYS MUST ALL BE SAME LENGTH" . Please guide me with this @Sameeresque

Comment: I would suggest padding to make all arrays equal in length. See this [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)